# execute shell command with tcl

Tags: shell, grep, tcl

I want to execute the folowing shell command by tcl :

```
cat $file_path/file | grep test > $file_path/des_file
```

I use exec but I got the following error:

```
cat :|grep No such file or directory
```

how to make this command works fine with tcl

Comment: From the error message it looks like the file does not exists in the directory. Check the file's existence. Print the `file_path` and make sure it is not empty.

Comment: please update your Q with the actual `tcl exec` call. It looks like you may need to add spaces so your cmd looks like a cmd-line invocation, ie. `cat /path/to/file | grep ...` Also, you can reduce this to `grep test /p/2/file > out`. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm betting that you're *actually* writing this:

```
cat $file_path/file |grep test > $file_path/des_file
```

With *no* space between `|` and `grep`. Tcl's `exec` cares about this since it assembles the pipeline without going to an external shell, and it is rather more finicky about these things.

One of the alternatives, only suitable where you don't have spaces in pathnames, is to do:

```
# Or however you want to make the script, such as popping up a dialog box in a GUI
set shell_script "cat $file_path/file |grep test > $file_path/des_file"
exec sh -c $shell_script
```

Though you can do it simply without that `cat` too:

```
exec grep test < $file_path/file > $file_path/des_file
```

That said, since it is `grep` you can do it *entirely* in Tcl:

```
# Read in all the lines
set f [open $file_path/file]
set lines [split [read $f] \n]
close $f

# Filter the lines
set matches [lsearch -all -inline -glob $lines *test*]

# Write out the filtered lines
set f [open $file_path/des_file w]
puts $f [join $matches \n]
close $f
```

The `-regexp` option to `lsearch` is a closer match to what `grep` does than `-glob`, but it's slower and overkill for this case.